# When would you not use a strongly-typed ASP.NET MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, strongly-typed-view

Assuming that an ASP.NET MVC View is going to show data, is there any scenario where you would not want to use a strongly-typed view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should follow the practice of always using strongly typed views, unless no model isused at all like previously mentioned for pages like login.

Answer (score 6):

Places where there is no model -- like Logon/Logoff.

Comment: This is the only reason I can see for not using a strongly-typed view, any other use would be just asking for trouble!

Answer (score 0):

I'm forced to put some data in layout. Cause I couldn't find any good way to make strongly typed layout, I'm passing necessary data through controller base class and picking it up at layout through indexer of viewData by key.

For partialviews i just nest form models, no problems there i guess.